# Failed to download images via url in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-crawler

I have found the address of the image in the source code of the web page.
Related content are shown as follows:

```
<div class="fwr_page_box">
    <div class="fwr_page" id="PageContainer_0" style="width: 1200px; height: 1696px; margin-left: 815px;">
        <div id="Wrap_0" class="fwr_page_wrap border  fwr_hidden" style="width: 1200px; height: 1696px;"></div>
        <div class="loadingBg" id="loadingBg0" style="width:1200;height:1696;">
            <img alt="" src="http://162.105.134.188/store/z6MY4xILLZ4Adov3uF7aOQ11/P01_00001.jpg" id="ViewContainer_BG_0" class="border  fwr_page_bg_image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I can extract the url (http://162.105.134.188/store/z6MY4xILLZ4Adov3uF7aOQ11/P01_00001.jpg) with chrome browser, and then download it manually. The figure size is about 87 kb.

However, when I tried to batch download those images via **wget** or **python urllib**

```
end_page = 117
for i in range(0,end_page,1):
    os.system("wget http://162.105.134.188/store/z6MY4xILLZ4Adov3uF7aOQ11/P01_%s.jpg" %"{:05d}".format(i))
```

Those files can be downloaded, while the figure size are only  82 bit without any content.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic html with the images are loaded by Javascript, which isn't loaded by wget or urllib

Use `selenium` to simulate a Chrome browser, and extract content from there